# How to assign variable from another dynamic variable in YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

I need to find an open port from the range of ports, and then assign that port to the variable. I decided to use wait_for with a loop. But I can't' figure it out how to 'extract' exact value. Example:

```
- name: check open port
  wait_for:
    host: '0.0.0.0'
    port: '{{ item }}'
    delay: 0
    state: started
    timeout: 1
  ignore_errors: true      
  loop:
  - 22222
  - 33333
  - 44444
  register: temp_port_check
```

Then how can I find/filter an open port and assign it to another variable, say "open_port" and if all ports are closed set default port = 11111?

I'm thinking something like:

```
- name: set fact current open port
  set_fact:
    open_port: in pseudo 'find openned port in temp_port_check else = 11111'
```

results of temp_port_check:

```
ok: [0.0.0.0] => {
    "msg": "Out: [{'_ansible_parsed': True, 'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': 22222, '_ansible_item_result': True, u'elapsed': 1, u'failed': True, u'msg': u'Timeout when waiting for 0.0.0.0:22222', u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'active_connection_states': [u'ESTABLISHED', u'FIN_WAIT1', u'FIN_WAIT2', u'SYN_RECV', u'SYN_SENT', u'TIME_WAIT'], u'host': u'0.0.0.0', u'connect_timeout': 5, u'delay': 0, u'search_regex': None, u'state': u'started', u'sleep': 1, u'timeout': 1, u'exclude_hosts': None, u'msg': None, u'path': None, u'port': 22222}}, '_ansible_item_label': 22222}, {'_ansible_parsed': True, 'changed': False, '_ansible_item_label': 33333, 'failed': False, '_ansible_item_result': True, u'elapsed': 0, 'item': 33333, u'state': u'started', u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'active_connection_states': [u'ESTABLISHED', u'FIN_WAIT1', u'FIN_WAIT2', u'SYN_RECV', u'SYN_SENT', u'TIME_WAIT'], u'host': u'0.0.0.0', u'connect_timeout': 5, u'delay': 0, u'search_regex': None, u'state': u'started', u'sleep': 1, u'timeout': 1, u'exclude_hosts': None, u'msg': None, u'path': None, u'port': 33333}}, u'path': None, u'search_regex': None, u'port': 33333, '_ansible_ignore_errors': True, '_ansible_no_log': False}, {'_ansible_parsed': True, 'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': 44444, '_ansible_item_result': True, u'elapsed': 1, u'failed': True, u'msg': u'Timeout when waiting for 0.0.0.0:44444', u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'active_connection_states': [u'ESTABLISHED', u'FIN_WAIT1', u'FIN_WAIT2', u'SYN_RECV', u'SYN_SENT', u'TIME_WAIT'], u'host': u'0.0.0.0', u'connect_timeout': 5, u'delay': 0, u'search_regex': None, u'state': u'started', u'sleep': 1, u'timeout': 1, u'exclude_hosts': None, u'msg': None, u'path': None, u'port': 44444}}, '_ansible_item_label': 44444}]"
}
```

how to extract value of _ansible_item_label': 33333 which staus'failed': False ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all ports are closed the play below

```
- name: List open_ports
  set_fact:
    open_ports: []
- set_fact:
    open_ports: "{{ open_ports + [ item.item ] }}"
  loop: "{{ temp_port_check.results }}"
  when: not item.failed
- name: Set default port
  set_fact:
    open_port: "{{ (open_ports|length == 0)|ternary('11111', open_ports.0) }}"
- debug:
    var: open_port
```

gives:

```
"open_port": "11111"
```

otherwise first open port will be assigned to *open_port*.